# Cannot Pull Heroku Database to Local

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

So I'm trying to pull data from my website through the following command:

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL mylocaldb --app devhaven
```

But it spews out this error:

```
DL is deprecated please use Fiddle 
 ! 'createdb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 ! operable program or batch file.
 !
 ! Unable to create new local database. Ensure your local Postgres is working and try again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that 1) PostgreSQL is installed and running locally and 2) the PostgreSQL command line tools are in your `PATH`. The error about `createdb` not being recognized indicates that the commands are not available.